# C# Error while executing function from oracle database

Tags: c#, database, oracle, function

I'm trying to execute oracle function from my c# code. But everytime I got this error:

ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'functionName'

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored

This is my C# code:

```
OracleCommand cmnd = new OracleCommand();
cmnd.Connection = getConnection();
cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmnd.CommandText = "Schema.functionName";

OracleParameter oracDevice = new OracleParameter("id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
oracDevice.Value = dsno;
cmnd.Parameters.Add(oracDevice);
OracleParameter oracReason = new OracleParameter("r", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
oracReason.Value = alarmName;
cmnd.Parameters.Add(oracReason);
OracleParameter oraStartLat = new OracleParameter("slat", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraStartLat.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(latitude);
cmnd.Parameters.Add(oraStartLat);
OracleParameter oraStartLon = new OracleParameter("slon", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraStartLon.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(longitude);
cmnd.Parameters.Add(oraStartLon);
OracleParameter oraStopLat = new OracleParameter("stoplat", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraStopLat.Value = 0;
cmnd.Parameters.Add(oraStopLat);
OracleParameter oraStopLon = new OracleParameter("stoplon", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraStopLon.Value = 0;
cmnd.Parameters.Add(oraStopLon);

string correctStringDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
DateTime correctDate = DateTime.ParseExact(correctStringDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

OracleParameter oraStartDate = new OracleParameter("dStart", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraStartDate.Value = correctDate; //String.Format($"{date:MM/dd/yyyy HH:m:ss tt}");
cmnd.Parameters.Add(oraStartDate);
//Console.WriteLine(String.Format(String.Format($"{date:MM/dd/yyyy HH:m:ss tt}")));
OracleParameter oraStopDate = new OracleParameter("dStop", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraStopDate.Value = correctDate; //String.Format($"{date:MM/dd/yyyy HH:m:ss tt}");
cmnd.Parameters.Add(oraStopDate);

OracleParameter id = new OracleParameter("returnId", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
cmnd.Parameters.Add(id);

cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var idOfRow = Convert.ToInt32(cmnd.Parameters["returnId"].Value);
```

And here are function's parameters:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION functioName
  ( id varchar,
    r varchar,
    slat in number,
    slon in number,
    stoplat in number,
    stoplon in number,
    dStart in date,
    dStop in date)
  RETURN  number IS
  nid number;
  dsf number;
  eve number;
```

I was trying many different solutions - trying to save string date format as date, changing oracleDbType from Decimal to Double/Int32 or 16. Nothing worked and the error was still the same. Also I put return parameter as first, but it didn't fix a problem. I know that probably is small error which I cannot see, but for me it looks like I was trying everything. Maybe here there will be someone who can help me with that.

Comment: I'm not an oracle guy, but shouldn't the name of the parameter for the return value have the same name as in the statement? Did you try replacing `"returnId"` with `"number"`?